When Barbie Alexandra says, "I don't even know how I got here", is she refering to a physical location or a metaphorical or emotional state?
Girl Barbie attempts to un-brainwash Barbie Alexandra:

TEEN TALK BARBIE: You’re a writer. This is your Nobel Prize. Remember?
BARBIE ALEXANDRA: Oh my God, I don’t even know how I got here. I don’t
deserve this!

Does "here" refer to a physical location or a metaphorical or emotional state?

I considered that, given her origins, this might obliquely refer to the lack of a navel.

Neither: "Here" refers to a moment in a developmental trajectory through Barbie Alexandra's personal history. In this usage it is effectively synonymous with "How did I get to this point in my life?"

The script describes her speech thusly.

[Barbie Alexandra goes into one of those acceptance speeches
women give, totally self-effacing and not embracing the win.]
BARBIE ALEXANDRA: Oh my God, I don’t even know how I got here. I don’t deserve this! I’d like to thank Ken.

It's clear that she means 'I'm not sure how I ended up here in my life (e.g. on this stage, being honoured by all of you)'
